# How to add motion effects in video like zoom in, zoom out, move left using AVMutableComposition swift iOS

Tags: ios, video, motion, avmutablecomposition

I am trying to add motion effects in the video like zoom in, zoom out, move left & move right and export as a new video using AVMutableComposition in Swift. Currently, I am not getting animation/effects in video.

I have tried to add animation to the video instruction 'AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction' layer in AVMutableComposition but it's not working.

Comment: Please review [ask] ... we need to see the code you've written to **try** to get your effect in order to help you fix it.